slick slider is not working in Linus-OS, fire-fox-Broswer,(for desktop)
in linux-OS,In a website i used slick slider, i downloaded the bundle and used the links. All are good in other browser even in fire-fox "when we inspect it for mobile", but for desktop it is not showing anything.
I inspected the css on network where in the slick slider's transferred is shown "cached" in fire-fox where-as in other browser it shows "memory cached".
